# How to check values in database on breakpoint during phpunit testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

## Background

I'm currently debugging some old unit tests in my code base, and I found a failing unit test at this point:

```
    $this->seeInDatabase('table', [
        'amount'   => //some value,
    ]);
```

in my phpunit.xml I'm running the tests against my `testing` env:

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
```

## Question

I would like to check the value that's actually stored on the database in my unittest environment. However, when I put a break point right before the `seeInDatabase` line, nothing appears at all in the database (the same happens when I try to run tinker like so:

```
php artisan tinker --env=testing
```

ideas?